# Pushing Values into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a problem with populating an array based on another array.

It seems when I push a value onto a specific index in the array, it is populating all indexes.

#### Code

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public matrix: number[] = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
    42, 43, 44, 45,
  ];
  public matrixColumns: number[][] = [];
  public expectedMatrixColumns: number[][] = [
    [1, 10, 19, 28, 37],
    [2, 11, 20, 29, 38],
    [3, 12, 21, 30, 39],
    [4, 13, 22, 31, 40],
    [5, 14, 23, 32, 41],
    [6, 15, 24, 33, 42],
    [7, 16, 25, 34, 43],
    [8, 17, 26, 35, 44],
    [9, 18, 27, 36, 45],
  ];
  public numberofColumns: number = 9;
  columnStartIndex: number = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.createColumnMatrix();
  }

  createColumnMatrix() {
    let columnsMatrix = [];
    let numberRows = this.matrix.length / this.numberofColumns;
    let matrixIndex = 0;

    for (let index = 0; index < this.numberofColumns; index++) {
      this.matrixColumns.push([]);
    }
    let columnIndex: number = 0;
    this.matrix.forEach((number, matrixIndex) => {
      debugger;
      this.matrixColumns[columnIndex].push(this.matrix[matrixIndex]);
      debugger;
      matrixIndex = matrixIndex + 1;
      columnIndex = columnIndex + 1;
      if (columnIndex > this.numberofColumns - 1) {
        columnIndex = 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Demo Project

Here is a JavaScript version that reproduces the problem:

```js
class AppComponent {
  matrix = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
    42, 43, 44, 45,
  ];
  matrixColumns = [];
  expectedMatrixColumns = [
    [1, 10, 19, 28, 37],
    [2, 11, 20, 29, 38],
    [3, 12, 21, 30, 39],
    [4, 13, 22, 31, 40],
    [5, 14, 23, 32, 41],
    [6, 15, 24, 33, 42],
    [7, 16, 25, 34, 43],
    [8, 17, 26, 35, 44],
    [9, 18, 27, 36, 45],
  ];
  numberofColumns = 9;
  columnStartIndex = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.createColumnMatrix();
  }

  createColumnMatrix() {
    let columnsMatrix = [];
    let numberRows = this.matrix.length / this.numberofColumns;
    let matrixIndex = 0;

    for (let index = 0; index < this.numberofColumns; index++) {
      this.matrixColumns.push(columnsMatrix);
    }
    let columnIndex = 0;
    this.matrix.forEach((number, matrixIndex) => {
      this.matrixColumns[columnIndex].push(this.matrix[matrixIndex]);
      matrixIndex = matrixIndex + 1;
      columnIndex = columnIndex + 1;
      if (columnIndex > this.numberofColumns - 1) {
        columnIndex = 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

let component = new AppComponent();
for (let row of component.matrixColumns) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
}
```

#### Problem

If you look at this line in the code:

```
this.matrixColumns[columnIndex].push(this.matrix[matrixIndex]);
```

It is pushing the first value in the array (matrix which is 1), into every index in my second array `matrixColumns`.

#### Expected output

```
[1, 10, 19, 28, 37]
[2, 11, 20, 29, 38]
[3, 12, 21, 30, 39]
[4, 13, 22, 31, 40]
[5, 14, 23, 32, 41]
[6, 15, 24, 33, 42]
[7, 16, 25, 34, 43]
[8, 17, 26, 35, 44]
[9, 18, 27, 36, 45]
```

#### Actual output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]
```

Comment: @trincot I have embedded it, this is the line that seems to be pushing into all indexes of the second array.  this.matrixColumns[columnIndex].push(this.matrix[matrixIndex]);  when I debug this statement this.matrixColumns is empty before i hit this line, then immediately after the line, every index in the array is populated.  Given I am specifically pushing into an specific index, I don't understand why that is happening 

It is pushing the first value in the array (matrix which is 1), into every index in my second array matrixColumns.

Comment: The downside of this stackblitz link is that you are updating the code, and so it no longer represents the problem.

Comment: was just trying out one of the suggestions - thanks

Comment: I removed those links, and replaced them by a runnable Stack Snippet inside the question. Hope it is OK for you.

Comment: No problem much appreciated, I have learned a lot from this exercise, thanks to all who have assisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const buildMatrix = (data, columns) => data.reduce((res, d, i) => {
  const row = i % columns
  const rowData = [...(res[row] || []), d]
  res[row] = rowData
  return res
}, [])

const data = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
    42, 43, 44, 45,
  ];
  
const matrix = buildMatrix(data, 9)

console.log(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have *one* `columnsMatrix` array. After pushing its reference to `this.matrixColumns` repeatedly, you end up with multiple references to the *same* array. So whether you then push to `this.matrixColumns[0]` or to `this.matrixColumns[1]` doesn't make a difference, ... you're always pushing to the same array.

You can solve this by pushing a *new* array unto `this.matrixColumns` at every call of `push`.

So replace:

```
this.matrixColumns.push(columnsMatrix);
```

with:

```
this.matrixColumns.push([]);
```

#### Simplified code

Not your question, but you can do this as follows:

```
this.matrixColumns = Array.from({length: this.numberofColumns}, (_, i) =>
    Array.from({length: numberRows}, (_, j) => matrix[i + j*numberRows])
);
```

```js
let matrix = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
    42, 43, 44, 45,
];
let numberofColumns = 9;
let numberofRows = Math.ceil(matrix.length / numberofColumns);
// logic
let matrixColumns = Array.from({length: numberofColumns}, (_, i) =>
    Array.from({length: numberofRows}, (_, j) => matrix[i + j*numberofRows])
);
// display
for (const row of matrixColumns) console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two dimensions something like

```
this.matrixColumns[columnIndex][matrixIndex].push(this.matrix[columnIndex][matrixIndex]);
```